# Tailwind CSS or Bootstrap? Which is considered good practice?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, tailwind-css

I have been using bootstrap in my projects but I get the feeling that is not good practice for web developers. I have some colleagues recommending Tailwind CSS. Which should I use as good practice in my HTML?

Comment: I think your comparison is wrong because bootstrap provides a UI component with some utility classes where tailwind CSS provides only utility classes for rapid development. I prefer to use bootstrap here.

Comment: Yep per the above comment Bootstrap is more opinionated design-wise which is the main difference. Both are "good practice" in their own way.

Comment: Be prepared for a religious debate!  :D I've found this post by Tailwind's creator, Adam Wathan, useful and illuminating: https://adamwathan.me/css-utility-classes-and-separation-of-concerns/

Answer (score 7):

The answer to the question that you are asking really depends on who you ask. You can achieve good practice for CSS with both frameworks, but it really comes to what you consider as a good practice.

You can find various articles on the web telling you about best practices for CSS, such as [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/30-css-best-practices-for-beginners--net-6741).

I encourage you to read more about CSS and the best practices for CSS in general, then you should start to read about both frameworks in depth, and also try both of them on some projects to really decide which one suits you better. But in the end, good practice can be achieved with both, but you need to understand why are you using one of them. Also, have in mind that they are different paradigms and you should read about it as well [Tailwind CSS vs Bootstrap: Learn about the differences](https://themesberg.com/blog/design/tailwind-css-vs-bootstrap). Once you understand all of this, you will be able to tell, which is better for you and the projects that you are working on.